# OO: Good method for maintaining consistency between related objects

Tags: oop, consistency

I have two classes, Server and Application, with a many-to-many relationship: a server can run multiple applications, an application can run across multiple servers. A third class, Host, represents a single application on a single server, including references to the Application and Server objects as well as additional data such as the amount of disk space used by the application on the server. Both Server and Application objects contain a list of all their hosts: hence, Applications know about Hosts and Hosts know about Applications, and Servers know about Hosts and Hosts know about Servers.

The purpose of my project is to work out the schedule for migrating a bunch of applications onto new servers. Originally each application had a migration-start and migration-end date. Some applications also have start and end dates for virtualisation. Virtualisation occurs if the migration cannot be performed within the application's constraints (never mind what these are). It occurs prior to the migration and frees the application from its constraints. An object called 'Schedule' is held by the Application object, which includes these 4 dates as well as a boolean flag to say whether it is to be virtualised, and a list of 'months' which contain the man-hours required to migrate (or virtualise) the application in each particular month.

We now want to allow servers to undergo virtualisation separately, on a specified date. All the applications (or parts of applications, i.e. hosts) on these servers will be virtualised on this date; they will be migrated along with the rest of the application. We originally decided to have the server class hold its own Schedule object. The virtualisation dates were then set in the server. However, we decided we wanted to keep the server and application schedules consistent - so that, for example, the server schedule's migration-start and end dates should be set to the earliest start and latest end dates, respectively, of all applications running on that server. This meant that every time we updated the Application dates, we had to remember to update all its server dates (via the host object). Or, if we wanted to update the Application's man-hours for a particular month, we had to update the server's man-hours also.

Then we thought about putting a single Schedule object inside each Host object. This solves the consistency problem, but leads to quite a bit of redundancy: since all Host objects belonging to an application will necessarily have the same migration dates (but possibly different virtualisation dates), when you set the migration dates for an app, you have to set the same dates for every host. Also, there are a few instances where we need to work out the earliest-start and latest-finish dates for servers AND applications, as above. This would involve either: holding this data in each of the application and server objects (effectively giving each its own Schedule, thereby brining back problems with consistency), or: calculating this data on-the-fly each time it is needed, by looping through all the hosts' schedules. The same goes for the man-hours required by an application each month, which is calculated at the application level, fractioned into hours for each host per month, and then recalculated when we need to figure it out at the application level again. This is, as you would expect, not efficient in the slightest.

This isn't a straightforward question, but I'm wondering if there are any accepted strategies for dealing with this sort of situation. Sorry in advance for the prolixity of my post; hopefully I've made the situation clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is complex once we get into 3rd paragraph onwards

I will use the following design principle

1. Keep Application, Server, Host objects contain the minimum required behaviors and states.

For example, Application Object may contain start date, end date and virtualization start and virtualization end dates. Think whether it require to contain a list of servers? or instance of Host?

1. Then a think about a small frame work like this.

   a) MigrationManager who does the complete process of Migration using  List

b) MigratioContext will composite information for migration process.

c) ErrorContext will composite the error and exception handling

Migration Manager gets an instance of Scheduler and schedules the migration

In this way we can gradually evolve a frame work kind of stuff around the core business object and business logic.

The important thing to remember

1. Separation of Concerns.
2. Reusability of Code: For exmple Your Application object may  not be  required to tied up the whole migration process. Instead those things can be done by another object

(This answer is based on my high level understanding and assumptions that could be wrong. But I think you may get some directions to build the application to meet the requirements)

Once more suggestion I have. Use a Modeling Tool such as StarUML or ArgoUML to put your ideas in a pictorial form. This will help all of the members to get into the question very quickly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming is that to the extent possible, every mutable aspect of state should at all times have exactly one well-defined owner (that owner may, in turn, be owned by exactly one other entity, which is in turned by one other entity, etc.).  Other objects and entities may hold references to that mutable state, but any such references should be thought of in terms of the owner.  For example, if a method accepts a reference to a collection and is supposed to to populate it, the method would not think in terms of operating on a collection it owns, but rather in terms of operating on a collection owned by someone else, for the benefit of that entity.

Sometimes it is necessary to have various objects to have separate copies of what is supposed to be the same mutable state.  This situation frequently arises in things like graphical user interfaces, where an object might "own" the rotational angle of an object, but a display control might need to cache a private rendering of that object in its current orientation.  Handling of such cases may be greatly simplified in cases where one object is designated the absolute master, and it keeps other objects notified of its state.  It will be greatly complicated if there are multiple objects, none of which has exclusive ownership, but all of which are supposed to nonetheless keep in sync with each other.

If you can work your model so that no piece of state needs to be duplicated, I would highly recommend doing so.  It's crucial, though, that your model be capable of representing all scenarios of interest, including the possibility that two things which are supposed to be in the same state, might not be.  What's most important is that every aspect of state has a well-defined chain of ownership, so that when an aspect of state is changed, one can say whose state is affected.